# Google Script - Transform a script to launch it via a checkBox with "ScriptApp.newTrigger" + onEdit function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need your help in order to modify my script "Version via button.gs" which works well. To launch it, you need to click on a button in the sheet "Mat & Comp Quick Search" present in the field "A1":
Quick Aim of the script:

- Scan datas in this spreadsheet (link hereafter), sheet "Datas from xxxx"
- Vlookup in another  spreadsheet  B
- Paste these values in this spreadsheet (link hereafter), sheet "Mat & Comp Quick Search",corresponding of the datas scanned
  -...

1st help:
I am trying to modify it, in the script "Version with OnEdit.gs", to do the same thing but in launching the script when the user has ticked the checkbox in the sheet "Summary" in the field "C36".
To do it, it is not possible to use simple trigger onEdit due to my script copy data in another spreadsheet and paste them in the sheet "Mat & Comp Quick Search".
What is the good way to do that?

```js
// Creates an onEdit trigger for a spreadsheet
function createTrigger() {
  let sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Summary");
  if(sheetName.indexOf('Summary')  && column == 3 && row == 36){
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('firstExtractFromBdd')
    .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
    .onEdit()
    .create();
  } 
}

function firstExtractFromBdd() {

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Delete Duplicate lines from Datas to Mat & Comp Quick Search sheet
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var ss, dataInput, a;

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheetTarget = ss.getSheetByName('Mat & Comp Quick Search');
var clearRange = sheetTarget.getRange("A9:N199");
clearRange.clearContent();

.........
```

2nd question:
My spreadsheet B are in the limits of google sheet capacity (around 10 million of cells), due to that in my operational case, the script is very long around 300seconds.
Have you a solution to reduce the time of this script?

Herefafter the link to my sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Hvu1BurYHug9F8UeuZmbP4IR4hQaNx4OIUJOWQj-Y9Q/edit?usp=sharing

I hope that my explanations are enough !
Thanks a lot in advance for your help.
Regards.

Comment: Have you reviewed the option to split the Sheets, mainly because if you keep adding data to it, it would eventually break or not even run.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `1st help:`. Can I ask you abut the detail of it? And, about `2nd question:`, where is `this script` of `Have you a solution to reduce the time of this script?`?

Comment: @Tanaike: In fact, the function firstExtractFromBdd() works well, when the script is launched manually via the button. But I would like to launch it automatically when the checkbox is ticked. I know that I cannot use a simple trigger onEdit but used a trigger via the function ScriptApp.newTrigger with condition. And it is why I ask your help to find me a solution !

Comment: @RicardoJoseVelasquezCruz : No I didn't. Is it mandatory to use the function opensheetbyid because I think this the reason why the script is long